# D3 Charts : How to add a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add tooltip for all my nodes included in my tree chart.

```
    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .text("a simple tooltip");
```

and try to show a tooltip box when the user mouseover() it, but doesn't work and gives no exception.

I have created a demo base on my current stage : http://jsfiddle.net/qvco2Ljy/119/

Comment: Check [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp).

Comment: I thought I should better using the d3 API thing instead of CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `return` and set the `x` and `y` positions of the tooltip:

```
tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
    .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 6 + 'px')
    .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px');
```

Don't forget to make it disappear in the `mouseout`:

```
tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden")
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dv8cn0xu/

Comment: Basically the codes work in the JSfiddle but not in my code.

Comment: You'll have to give more details: what doesn't work? Are you using a server? Do you get any console message?

Comment: I simply copy and paste without modifications. But it's not working still and give out no exception

Comment: guess is because of the CSS

Comment: fixed, it's just my css opacity issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can append tooltip to each node as follows

```
node.append("svg:title")
    .text(function (d) {
        return "Some Text based on Data (d)";
    });
```